# NSTimer [timer invalidate] doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, nstimer

The timer doesn't stop, not in the `stopButtonPressed` and not if the `sec` value is 0.
The timer should e.g. count from 100 to 0. If the value == 0 or the stop button is pressed the timer should stop! But it continues counting.

Where is my mistake?
I've tried different ways but nothing works.

Here is the code:

in .h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSTimer *countdownTimer;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)timer {

    sec = sec - 1;
    int minutes = sec / 60;
    int seconds = sec - (minutes * 60);

    [_timerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds]];

    if (sec == 0) {
        [_countdownTimer invalidate];
        _countdownTimer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)startTimer {

    _countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [self startTimer];
    [_startButton setHidden:YES];
    [_stopButton setHidden:NO];
}

- (IBAction)stopButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [_stopButton setHidden:YES];
    [_countdownTimer invalidate];
    [_startButton setHidden:NO];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You've failed to describe any symptoms.

Comment: The timer should e.g. count from 100 to 0. If the value == 0 the timer should stop! But it continues counting

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have tried this piece of code and it works perfectly, the timer stops when you press stopButton and when sec==0;

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSTimer*_countdownTimer;
    int sec;
}

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel*_timerLabel;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton*_startButton;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton*_stopButton;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    sec=100;
}

- (void)timer {

    sec = sec - 1;
    int minutes = sec / 60;
    int seconds = sec - (minutes * 60);

    [self._timerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds]];

    if (sec == 0) {
        [_countdownTimer invalidate];
        _countdownTimer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)startTimer {
    _countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self startTimer];
    [self._startButton setHidden:YES];
    [self._stopButton setHidden:NO];
}

- (IBAction)stopButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self._stopButton setHidden:YES];
    [_countdownTimer invalidate];
    _countdownTimer=nil;
    [self._startButton setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary to stop the timer.

Comment: Maybe your _stopButton is not connected to your IBAction and that is why is not stopping. I have tried this code and it worked. @Fist

Comment: See my edit and try it, i hope it works for you. @Fist

Comment: Okay, I've tried it in a new project and it works. So I have to look in my whole code and find the reason. Thanks for your help! Now I know more than before.